# regular expression for comma separated Numeric values

Tags: regex

can you please help me to write a regular expression where it allows comma separated Numeric values. Below is the Expression that i have tried.

Expression :  `/^[0-9,]+$/`

Test String : `123,111` --> Shows as Match --> Correct

Test String : `123,111,` -- > Shows as Match --> Incorrect --> if comma is specified it should follow with number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*$
```

You can construct it this way.

Comment: Thank you it worked... But may i know what does colon specifies in regex